# Google Docs export issues 401, 404 and 500

Tags: api, google-drive-api

I am trying to download all data from Google Drive into local folder using Google Drive SDK. Most documents are downloaded without any issues. But there are some documents with strange errors.

At the first all these documents are listed in [`Files: list`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/list) result. [`Files: get`](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get) returns me information about these files.

I see that these files are owned by user I use to download documents:

```
[userPermission] => Google_Permission Object
    (
        [withLink] => 
        [kind] => drive#permission
        [name] => 
        [value] => 
        [id] => me
        [authKey] => 
        [etag] => "I8bbqc4qdR0X_1JlJgkO3gbuFf8/HQBSku0dMcS5bNfsSFuNdlHwJmk"
        [role] => owner
        [photoLink] => 
        [type] => user
        [additionalRoles] => 
        [selfLink] => https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/..../permissions/me
    )
```

But when I try export these files using one of `exportLinks` I receive errors.

#### HTTP Status 404

Documents:

```
Sorry, the file you have requested does not exist.
```

Spreadsheets:

```
Spreadsheet not found
Error 404
```

#### HTTP Status 401

On other account I receive error with HTTP Status 401:

```
Permission denied
Error 401
```

#### HTTP Status 500

And at the end there are a lot of errors with HTTP Status 500:

```
Conversion failed unexpectedly
Error 500
```

The main question - can I solve these issues? If no what can I say to users about these issues?

- Can I tell them that Google lost their data (when error 404 appears)?
- Can I promise that files will be downloaded little later (when error 500 appears)?
- How error `401 Permission denied` is possible if user owns his document?

**Update 1: This always returns 401 when I try to export**

```
{
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
    "thumbnailLink": null,
    "labels": {
        "restricted": false,
        "hidden": false,
        "viewed": false,
        "starred": false,
        "trashed": false
    },
    "indexableText": null,
    "explicitlyTrashed": null,
    "etag": "\"KYLl3b7q6n8KW2kbVvK9NFUdVkc/MTM4MjUzMDk0Mzc4Ng\"",
    "lastModifyingUserName": "*********",
    "writersCanShare": true,
    "id": "********************************",
    "title": "2012 09 14 col audit report lin",
    "ownerNames": [
        "***** *****"
    ],
    "sharedWithMeDate": "2013-10-23T12:21:57.688Z",
    "lastViewedByMeDate": null,
    "parents": [
        {
            "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/********************************/parents/***************",
            "kind": "drive#parentReference",
            "id": "***************",
            "isRoot": true,
            "parentLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/***************"
        }
    ],
    "exportLinks": {
        "application/pdf": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=********************************&exportFormat=pdf",
        "application/x-vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=********************************&exportFormat=ods",
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet": "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=********************************&exportFormat=xlsx"
    },
    "originalFilename": null,
    "description": null,
    "webContentLink": null,
    "editable": true,
    "kind": "drive#file",
    "quotaBytesUsed": "0",
    "fileSize": null,
    "createdDate": "2012-09-14T19:41:23.142Z",
    "md5Checksum": null,
    "imageMediaMetadata": null,
    "embedLink": "https://docs.google.com/a/mcclatchy.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=********************************&output=html&chrome=false&widget=true",
    "alternateLink": "https://docs.google.com/a/mcclatchy.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=********************************&usp=drivesdk",
    "modifiedByMeDate": null,
    "downloadUrl": null,
    "userPermission": {
        "withLink": null,
        "kind": "drive#permission",
        "name": null,
        "value": null,
        "id": "me",
        "authKey": null,
        "etag": "\"KYLl3b7q6n8KW2kbVvK9NFUdVkc/0Woj6kzdwLqBirUxVylXMFf6UNc\"",
        "role": "owner",
        "photoLink": null,
        "type": "user",
        "additionalRoles": null,
        "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/********************************/permissions/me"
    },
    "fileExtension": null,
    "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/********************************",
    "modifiedDate": "2013-10-23T12:22:23.786Z",
    "iconLink": "https://ssl.gstatic.com/docs/doclist/images/icon_11_spreadsheet_list.png",
    "owners": [
        {
            "kind": "drive#user",
            "displayName": "***** *****",
            "isAuthenticatedUser": true,
            "permissionId": "*****************"
        }
    ],
    "lastModifyingUser": {
        "kind": "drive#user",
        "displayName": "*********",
        "isAuthenticatedUser": false,
        "permissionId": "*****************"
    },
    "copyable": true,
    "shared": true,
    "appDataContents": false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have implemented proper retry logic.  See [handling API errors](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors).  Its possible that some of these are transient problems.

That page also discusses possible reasons for the specific error codes.  For example, 401 may mean your token has expired.

Comment: Thank You for your reply. `handling API errors` - was the first I read. I implemented retry logic and solved some errors, but problematic files are the same for each programm execution. Token expiration can't be a reason because programm downloads the next files with the same token without problems.

Comment: I assume you have full drive scope?  Do you have any details on the particular files that are failing?

Comment: Yes, I have full drive scope. What kind of details do You ask? I have full metadata.

Comment: What type of file? What export link?  If you have a specific example you could share that would be useful.

Comment: I added whole JSON that I receive from Google Drive for one of problematic files. Please, see "Update 1" in my post. Unfortunately, I am not sure if I may post here IDs of file or roles.